# NSTextView not displaying Undo/Redo action names

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsundomanager

`NSDocument`-based app with programmatically created `NSTextView` and other objects. App processes Undo and Redo actions accurately for both the text view and the other app objects. The Undo menu item accurately displays the action name for the custom app objects, set via

```
self.doc.undoManager?.setActionName(NSLocalizedString("widget change", comment: "undo/redo widget change"))
```

In `validateUserInterfaceItem`, confirm via log that `myTextView.undoManager?.undoActionName` is "Typing" after user has typed and "Paste" after the user has pasted. And yet, when the text view is active, the Undo menu item name will either be just "Undo" or continue to be "Undo widget change" or whatever the most recent non-text view action was. That is, any text view action seems to properly change the `undoActionName` but does not change the Undo menu item's name. Any suggestions for what to look at or try? fwiw, the text view's undo manager is the doc's undo manager.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the document's `undoManager?.undoActionName` also "Typing"?

Comment: Yes. The doc and text view have the same undo manager.